# What is a FTDI chip? How does USB communicate with Arduino?

Tags: arduino, usb, serial, ftdi

What is a FTDI chip?

Is this used in Arduino to communicate to the laptop? I think that the voltage levels are different on USB and Arduino?

Comment: Second question - yes. The first one - too broad, the third one - unclear.

Comment: Go [there](http://www.ftdichip.com/Products/ICs/FT232R.htm) and start reading. It is all pretty explanatory. And the datasheet has lots of connection examples.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What is a FTDI chip?

It's a chip made by Future Technologies Devices International, http://www.ftdichip.com.  They seem to specialize in chips that connect directly to USB, then offer a different interface that is more convenient for simple hardware to connect to.

> Is this used in Arduino to communicate to the laptop?

What laptop?  No laptop has been previously mentioned, so this question makes no sense.

A arduino is just a microcontroller with sugar coating so that people that don't know what they are doing can still accomplish certain things.  Since this site *is* about knowing what you're doing and understanding circuits, the mention of "arduino" is usually a indication that the question is off topic.

That said, a microcontroller could certainly use some flavors of FTDI chips to communicate with a PC over USB.

> I think that the voltage levels are different on USB and Arduino?

This is a silly question.  There is no way for us to know and then tell you what you think, even if it were on topic.

### General question-asking guidance

If you are asking something about a arduino, first think whether that's about the arduinoness, or a more general electronic or microcontroller problem.  If the first, then the question probably doesn't belong here since arduinos are about hiding what is really going on under the hood.  If the second, then there is no need to mention "ardiuno", so don't.

As a corrolary, if a question does mention "arduino", then it either means the OP just wants to get something done without bothering to understand the technology, or the OP hasn't thought it out very carefully and the question isn't really arduino-specific.  Either way, it's hard to take the question seriously, and any slack that might have been given to the OP has vanished.

Comment: Thank you! You have written what I wanted to write for a long time, but I was afraid to step on many toes.

Comment: @Old: It seems no matter how many arduinees we tar and feather out of here, there's always another one asking for the same treatment.

Comment: There's also this: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

FTDI is a company (Future Technology Devices International Limited). What people typically refer to in this context is the FTDI FT232RL chip. [Datasheet here](http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/DataSheets/ICs/DS_FT232R.pdf)

As you can see from the datasheet, that particular chip is a USB<->UART chip. It is used to allow a PC, using the USB bus, to communicate with MCU chip on some models of Arduino.

Other chips, such as similar products from Prolific and the CH340 made by Nanjing-based WCH, can be used, as well as microcontrollers which have a USB interface.

Comment: +1 for referring to the context on which the word is usually used. I would add that other FTDI chips may do USB<->RS232 conversions instead, which are also USB to serial conversions. However, the converted voltages will be much higher (e.g. +/- 15 V) than the voltages typically involved in an UART protocol (e.g. 0 to 5 V) that most microcontrollers use in their "communication" pins `Tx` and `Rx`

Answer (score 1):

An "FTDI chip" usually refers to one of the USB to serial chips from [FTDI](http://www.ftdichip.com).  FTDI also makes other parts that aren't USB to serial, but their USB to serial chips are quite ubiquitous and are used on many development boards, including the Arduino board.  FTDI provides the chip and the associated driver, making it very convenient to add USB support to a device that uses a standard serial port in a world where serial ports are not available on most computers.  In general, the FTDI parts will implement a USB device interface on one side and some sort of serial or GPIO interface on the other side.

The voltage levels certainly are different, but that's not the only compatibility issue.  USB has specific timing requirements, has to run at specific bit rates, and has to implement a relatively complex set of functionality to properly interface with the host.  This requires a fair amount of specialized hardware.  Some microcontrollers contain USB interfaces including the ones on some of the newer Arduino boards, but for ones that don't it's not really possible to speak USB directly and the FTDI chip contains all of the necessary logic to do this in one convenient package.